# how do i go about populating my board with game counters?

Tags: java

[spacebattle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaZqi.png)

so far i was able to make a board composed of tiles using jlabels.  the next step of the game is for players Red and Blue, to take turns selecting a planet (by clicking on a planet tile) they initially control.  once a player clicks on a planet, a meeple counter should be placed on top of that tile planet.

the array data for the planets should also be updated so the owner of the planet be known. right now, i have no idea how to link my jlabel tiles with my variables.

if you can point me to the right direction, it will be much appreciated. thanks.

```
package SpaceBattle;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

//import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.swing.*;

public class spacebattle2 extends JFrame {

    JLabel[] tilelabel = new JLabel[31];
    JLabel[] hexlabel = new JLabel[31];



    ImageIcon tileicon, hexicon;

    int rownum, colnum;
    int c, r, xloc, yloc, hexctr, tilectr;
    int energy, ore, capacity;
    String labelname;
    String type;

    int numtiles = 31;
    int deckctr = 26;


    String[] tiledeck = new String[numtiles];
    int[] tilexloc = new int[numtiles];
    int[] tileyloc = new int[numtiles];

    int tileenergy[] = new int[numtiles];
    int tileore[] = new int[numtiles];
    int tilecapacity[] = new int[numtiles];
    String tiletype[] = new String[numtiles]; 
    String tilename[] = new String[numtiles];
    int tilemeeple[] = new int[numtiles];



    String[] hexnum = new String[numtiles];
    int[] hexxloc = new int[numtiles];
    int[] hexyloc = new int[numtiles];
    String[] hexempty = new String[numtiles];

    int hexenergy[] = new int[numtiles];
    int hexore[] = new int[numtiles];
    int hexcapacity[] = new int[numtiles];
    String hextype[] = new String[numtiles]; 
    String hexname[] = new String[numtiles];
    String hexplayer[] = new String[numtiles];

    String[] players = new String[6];
    String playerturn;

    int startingplanets = 2;
    int bluemaxplanet = startingplanets;
    int redmaxplanet = startingplanets;

    int numplanets = 7;
    int numspace = 24;
    int nonplayertiles = numplanets + numspace;

    String planetCode;
    String planetselected = "none";

    //selectPlanet
    String player = "Red";

    int i;




    public spacebattle2() {

    setLayout(null);    

    createDeck();
    shuffleDeck();
    drawBoard();
    //selectPlanet();

    }


    private void selectPlanet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(i = 0; i < numtiles; i++) {

            tilelabel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


                    System.out.println(i);


                }


                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                }

                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
    }









    private void shuffleDeck() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("shuffling deck...");

        Random r = new Random();
        int swapIndex;

        String temp;

        for(int startIndex = 0; startIndex < numtiles; startIndex++) {

            System.out.println(startIndex + " startIndex " + tiledeck[startIndex]);

            swapIndex = r.nextInt(numtiles);
            System.out.println(swapIndex + " swapIndex " + tiledeck[swapIndex]);

            if(swapIndex != startIndex) {

                temp = tiledeck[swapIndex];

                tiledeck[swapIndex] = tiledeck[startIndex];
                System.out.println("Moving " + startIndex +  " " + tiledeck[startIndex] + " startIndex to " + swapIndex + " swapIndex");

                tiledeck[startIndex] = temp;
                System.out.println("Moving " + temp +  " temp to " + startIndex + " startIndex");
            }           
        }
    }





    private void createDeck() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int s, p, xloc = 667, yloc = 10;




        /*******************************
         * 
         *  Create Space tiles
         * 
         ******************************/

        System.out.println("creating space tiles...");

        tilectr = 0;

        for(s= 0; s < numspace; s++) {

            tiledeck[tilectr] = "000";

            System.out.println(tilectr + " " + tiledeck[tilectr]);

            tilectr++;
        } 


        /**************************
         * 
         *  Create Planet tiles
         * 
         *************************/

        System.out.println("creating planet tiles...");

        for(p = 0; p < numplanets; p++) {

            energy = (int) (Math.random()*3 + 1);
            ore = (int) (Math.random()*3 +1);
            capacity = (int) (Math.random()*3 +1);


            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            stringBuffer.append("");
            stringBuffer.append(energy);
            stringBuffer.append(ore);
            stringBuffer.append(capacity);

            String planetCode = stringBuffer.toString();

            tiledeck[tilectr] = planetCode;

            System.out.println(tilectr + " " + tiledeck[tilectr]);
            tilectr++;
        }

    }



    private void drawBoard() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int xloc = 10;
        int yloc = 61;
        int hexctr = 0;


        int colnum = 7;
        int rownum = 4;

        xloc = 10;
        yloc = 61;
        hexctr = 0;


        colnum = 7;
        rownum = 4;

        int row = 0, col = 0, numtiles = 31;

        for(int c = 0; c < numtiles; c ++) {
            if(tiledeck[c] == "000") {
                System.out.println(c + " " + tiledeck[c] + " tile is space");
                tileenergy[c] = 0;
                tileore[c] = 0;
                tilecapacity[c] = 0;
                tiletype[c] = "space";
                tilename[c] = "space";

                tileicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/000.png"));   
                tilelabel[c] = new JLabel();
                tilelabel[c].setIcon(tileicon);

                tilelabel[c].setBounds(xloc, yloc, 115, 100);

                add(tilelabel[c]);

                yloc = yloc + 102;
                row++;

                if(row == rownum) {
                    xloc = xloc + 88;
                    row = 0;
                    col++;
                    if(col % 2 == 0) {
                        yloc = 61;
                        rownum = rownum - 1; 
                    }
                    else {
                        yloc = 10;
                        rownum = rownum + 1;
                    }
                }   
            }



            else {
                System.out.println(c + " " + tiledeck[c] +  " tile is planet");
                tileenergy[c] = Integer.parseInt(tiledeck[c].substring(0, 1));
                tileore[c] = Integer.parseInt(tiledeck[c].substring(1, 2));
                tilecapacity[c] = Integer.parseInt(tiledeck[c].substring(2, 3));
                tiletype[c] = "planet";
                tilemeeple[c] = 0;

                tileicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/" + tiledeck[c] + ".png"));   
                tilelabel[c] = new JLabel();
                tilelabel[c].setIcon(tileicon);
                tilelabel[c].setBounds(xloc, yloc, 115, 100);
                add(tilelabel[c]);

                yloc = yloc + 102;
                row++;

                if(row == rownum) {
                    xloc = xloc + 88;
                    row = 0;
                    col++;
                    if(col % 2 == 0) {
                        yloc = 61;
                        rownum = rownum - 1; 
                    }
                    else {
                        yloc = 10;
                        rownum = rownum + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private Object i(int numtiles2, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spacebattle2 board = new spacebattle2();
        board.setSize(900, 600);
        board.setResizable(false);
        board.setTitle("Space Battle");
        board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        board.setVisible(true);
    }//End void main

}
```

Comment: Instead of using JLabel directly, why not create a class that either extends JLabel or uses an instance of it.  You can then also include the owner's ID within that class. The same could also be done to associate other variables with a JLabel.

Comment: [getClientProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest restructuring the program to use a "tile" class to hold all the information related to a given tile. It can also be helpful to have a "tile manager" class that knows about the collection of tiles and how they relate to one another.

Here is what a tile class might look like for your program. I have tried not to change any functionality, only to reorganize things. You should be able to match everything up with your original program.

```
class TileInfo {
    TileManager manager;

    public JLabel label = new JLabel();
    public JLabel hexlabel = new JLabel();

    int xloc;
    int yloc;
    int energy;
    int ore;
    int capacity;
    String type;
    String name;
    int meeple;

    String hexnum;
    int hexxloc;
    int hexyloc;
    String hexempty;
    // etc...

    public TileInfo(Icon tileicon, int x, int y, TileManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
        label.setIcon(tileicon);
        label.setBounds(x, y, 115, 100);
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                manager.clickedTile(TileInfo.this);
            };
        });
    }
};
```

You can then extend this base class for "space" and "planet" tiles:

```
class SpaceTile extends TileInfo {
    public SpaceTile(Icon icon, int x, int y, TileManager manager) {
        super(icon, x, y, manager);
        energy = 0;
        ore = 0;
        capacity = 0;
        type = "space";
        name = "space";
    }
};

class PlanetTile extends TileInfo {
    public PlanetTile(Icon icon, int x, int y,
                      int energy, int ore, int capacity, TileManager manager) {
        super(icon, x, y, manager);
        this.energy = energy;
        this.ore = ore;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        type = "planet";
        meeple = 0;
    }
};
```

The subclasses are not strictly necessary in your example, but tile construction is slightly different in each case and this helps keep them straight.

Each `TileInfo` creates its own mouse listener, but passes the events up to the tile manager. The tile manager acts like a container and holds the array:

```
class TileManager {
    public int numtiles;
    public TileInfo[] tile;
    public String tiledeck[];

    public TileManager(int numtiles) {
        this.numtiles = numtiles;
        this.tile = new TileInfo[numtiles];
        this.tiledeck = new String[numtiles];
        System.out.printf("TileManager(%d): tile[%d]\n", numtiles, numtiles);
    }

    public void clickedTile(TileInfo tile) {
        if (tile instanceof SpaceTile) {
            System.out.println("clicked space tile " + tile.label.getBounds());
        } else if (tile instanceof PlanetTile) {
            System.out.println("clicked planet tile " + tile.label.getBounds());
        }
    }
};
```

Notice now you only need a single array. `TileManager` could override `ArrayList` if you like that better; I wanted to stick as closely as possible to your original program. The `clickedTile()` method handles mouse clicks on tiles, but since it is in the tile manager it can see all the tiles instead of just one. If, for example, you want to de-select tile A when you click on tile B, you need to be able to see both tiles.

Having a separate tile manager is not strictly necessary; you could leave this functionality in the `spacebattle2` class. I like to have a manager class to separate the functionality of creating, manipulating, and drawing groups of tiles, separate from gameplay. It acts sort of like a "tile library".

Finally, how this all fits into your main class. Lots of code omitted for clarity.

```
public class spacebattle2 extends JFrame {
    TileManager tiles = new TileManager(31);

    // didn't change anything except tiledeck[] now lives inside tiles
    // this method could be moved into the TileManager
    private void shuffleDeck() {
        for(int startIndex = 0; startIndex < tiles.numtiles; startIndex++) {
            swapIndex = r.nextInt(tiles.numtiles);
            if(swapIndex != startIndex) {
                temp = tiles.tiledeck[swapIndex];
                tiles.tiledeck[swapIndex] = tiles.tiledeck[startIndex];
                tiles.tiledeck[startIndex] = temp;
            }           
        }
    }

    void createTile(String deck, int xloc, int yloc) {
        tileicon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/" + deck + ".png"));   
        if (deck.equals("000")) {
            tiles.tile[c] = new SpaceTile(tileicon, xloc, yloc, tiles);
        } else {
            int energy = Integer.parseInt(deck.substring(0, 1));
            int ore = Integer.parseInt(deck.substring(1, 2));
            int capacity = Integer.parseInt(deck.substring(2, 3));
            tiles.tile[c] = new PlanetTile(tileicon, xloc, yloc, 0, 0, 0, tiles);
        }
        add(tiles.tile[c].label);
    }

    private void drawBoard() {
    /* ... */

        for(int c = 0; c < tiles.numtiles; c ++) {
            createTile(tiles.tiledeck[c], xloc, yloc);

            yloc = yloc + 102;
            row++;
            if(row == rownum) {
                xloc = xloc + 88;
                row = 0;
                col++;
                if(col % 2 == 0) {
                    yloc = 61;
                    rownum = rownum - 1; 
                } else {
                    yloc = 10;
                    rownum = rownum + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The loop in `drawBoard()` is simplified; it had a lot of duplicate code, so I factored that out and added a `createTile()` method to create the two types of tile.

Thare are still improvements that could be made. I would not consider a public array with public TileInfo variables to be ideal as a way to accessing your data, but did not want to change it so much that it is unrecognizable.

This is not meant to be a final design, but to suggest a way to organize the code in a way that will make it easier to work with, and also answer your question about how to associate data with tiles.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your feedback!  It will take me a while to absorb and understand your suggestions, as I am just programming in java through examples but I will do my best.